# PHPUnit assert method call at index and number of calls

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I need to assert 3 different method calls (of the same method) with different arguments and return values. I can do that using `$this->at()`. How can I also assert that *exactly* 3 calls where made?
Normally it would be easy using `$this->exactly(3)` but I can't use it in my case..

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [returnValueMap](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php) with your mock.  You are then able to use the `exactly(3)` and it will return the correct values for each call.

Slightly modified example from PHPUnit documentation:

```
public function testReturnValueMapStub()
{
    // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
                 ->getMock();

    // Create a map of arguments to return values.
    $map = array(
      array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
      array('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'),
      array('i', 'j', 'k', 'l'),
    );

    // Configure the stub.
    $stub->expects($this->exactly(3))
         ->method('doSomething')
         ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));

    // $stub->doSomething() returns different values depending on
    // the provided arguments.
    $this->assertEquals('d', $stub->doSomething('a', 'b', 'c'));
    $this->assertEquals('h', $stub->doSomething('e', 'f', 'g'));
}
```

Comment: And is there a way to also check the inputs with a map?

Comment: I was not able to find that.  And unfortunately, null is returned if a value not in the map is provided.

Comment: Would gladly use `returnValueMap()`, but my method needs to throw on one of the invocations.

Comment: Super old [thread](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/674) on the subject.